# user input in struct in C?

Tags: c, struct

```
int a;
scanf("%d",a);

typedef struct mylist {
    int info[a];
    struct mylist *link;

} Node;
```

this is my very simple struct and variable 'a' that don't work.

The thing which I want my program to do is to read input from the user and insert the digit into the struct (the user can determine the size of the array), however, I don't know how to do it since I get an error:

> "variably modified ‘info’ at file scope".

I want to know whether it is possible to do this in a simple way.

Comment: `scanf("%d", a);` should be `scanf("%d", &a);`

Comment: Use `int *info;` and use `malloc`: `Node n;`, `n.info = malloc((sizeof int) * a);`.

Comment: Use a _flexible array member_. But that must be the last member in a `struct`.

Comment: That won't work, the structure definition is created a the time of *compilation*, and you get the size as run-time. You need to come up with another way (like the two in the above comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @[David Hoelzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730616/1983495)

```
scanf("%d",a);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

If you are under C99 you can use [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
typedef struct mylist {
    struct mylist *link;
    int info[]; /* should be the last member */
} Node;
```

and then

```
Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node + (a * sizeof(int)));
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `scanf` into an integer you must pass a pointer.  You may want to check the documentation.

```
 scanf("%d", &a);
```

As far as using a variable to allocate data, you can do it, but you will want to use `malloc` most likely after defining your structure as a type.

Comment: What else does the documentation say that is very important about `scanf()`?

Comment: @iharob you should check it for errors like in my example

Comment: @tinky_winky Exactly, specially when the `"%d"` specifier is used, things can go very wrong if one assumes that *it worked*!

Comment: Exactly. Silently neglected errors are very very bad thing, though many seem to enjoy them!

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised that this question didn't get voted closed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must have pointer to array of correct size or use flexible array. Here is how to use a pointer initializing it to point to storage of proper size.

```
struct mylist {
    int *info;    // or int info[] at the end of struct def if C99 is used
    int info_size;
    struct mylist *link;
};

int main(void)
{
    int *array;
    struct mylist m;
    if (scanf("%d", &m.info_size) != 1)
    {
        perror("scanf failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // ok
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * m.info_size);
    if (array == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // ok, commit changes
    m.info = array;
```